# Conditional Join based on format of the values

Tags: sql, sql-server

at some point we've changed the format of the data coming into a table of ours. A stored procedure updates another table by matching ACC from one table to desc2 from another.

ACC is always in the following format: `B200001`, previously desc2 was in this format (and sometimes still is)

But more frequently it is in the following: `B200001 (1)`. If I trim the last three characters off the values with the parenthesis it matches just fine.

However if the value does not have the parenthesis it will trim some off of the value I want which causes it to match the wrong value in ACC.

How can I do a conditional join based on the value in desc2?

When desc2 contains (*)

```
UPDATE a
SET 
//values to set here.
FROM DB.dbo.TABLE a
JOIN TABLE2 c ON a.ACC = LTRIM(RTRIM((SUBSTRING(c.desc2,0,len(c.desc2)-2))))
JOIN TABLE3 i ON i.value = c.value
WHERE c.value in ('1','2')
```

When desc2 does not contain (*)

```
UPDATE a
SET 
//values to set here.
FROM DB.dbo.TABLE a
JOIN TABLE2 c ON a.ACC = c.desc2
JOIN TABLE3 i ON i.value = c.value
WHERE c.value in ('1','2')
```

Comment: You need `REPLACE` with `PATINDEX` to replace parenthesis and everything between  them with an empty string (`''`).  See http://shannonlowder.com/2005/03/string-manipulation-replace-patindex-and-regular-expressions/ or Google for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing the following:
It adds '(' to the string, then removes everything after the first occurrence of it.
This accounts for my older values that lack the parenthesis and the new format with the parenthesis. It trims any whitespace from the end of the value as well.

```
RTRIM(LEFT(c.desc_2 + '(',charindex('(',c.desc_2+'(')-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

This code alone will do the job for both

```
    UPDATE a
    SET //values to set here.
    FROM DB.dbo.TABLE a
    JOIN TABLE2 c ON a.ACC = SUBSTRING(c.desc2, 1, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',  c.desc2 )= 0 THEN LEN(c.desc2) ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', c.desc2)-1 END)
    JOIN TABLE3 i ON i.value = c.value
    WHERE c.value in ('1','2')
```

It will check for character ' ' and till space it retains the string
if ' ' is not present it gives out the entire string